# How to setup MongoDB to log to file and stdout?

Tags: mongodb, logging

I understand how to use [mongodb.conf to set logpath](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/#logpath) to log to a file or to stdout, but is there a way to log to both? E.g. pipe stdout to a log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [tee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tee_%28command%29) command in UNIX:

```
/opt/mongodb/bin/mongod | tee mongod.log
```

If mongodb logs to stdout tee "copies" all output to the file mongod.log.

Comment: I was hoping for something I could use in mongodb.conf but this definitely answers the question. Can just write that into a control script.  Thanks!

Comment: This also worked for WIndows in Powershell using Tee-Object.
example:
`. $binPath\$mongod -f $confPath | Tee-Object -FilePath $logPath`